# How to show images retrieved from JSON on page using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, angularjs

I am newbie to angular.js. I am developing a shoppingcart Application, I am getting a JSON Object from database from AJAX call. But I am not getting How to show all the images(url stored in fileLocation in JSON) from JSON response on to Html page using Angular js.

Here is my code:

My JSON

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "binaries": [
        {
            "fileLocation": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
            "username": "testuser3",
            "description": "The company required the 28-year-old's help on a matter the directors felt could affect the share price: its Wikipedia page. Short, uninteresting ."
        },
        {
            "fileLocation": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
            "username": "Sumanth",
            "description": "Sample"
        },
        {
            "fileLocation": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
            "username": "as",
            "description": "as"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

JSON is assigned to variable data

My Angularjs Controller:

```
 myAppDirectives.
  controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http,dateFilter) {
  $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8087/sportsrest/binaries/' }).success(function (data) {
   var result = data;
     var json=JSON.stringify(result);
     var data = JSON.parse(json);
     $scope.cart = data; // response data 
 }).
 error(function (data) {
     alert("error" + data);
     console.log(data);
 });
});
```

My HTML page:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" id="ng-app">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <article class="main-content" role="main">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="bookmarks-list">
          <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="data">
                 <h3>{{cart._embedded.binaries.username}}</h3>
                 <img ng-src="{{cart._embedded.binaries.fileLocation}}"/>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>    
</body>
</html>
```

Can Anyone please help me How to iterate through All the images on JSON object and show on HTML page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ijada thanks for replay.  i assigned json stored in data to $scope.cart in my controller code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` is not on the correct variable. It should be on the `cart._embedded.binaries` array:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in cart._embedded.binaries">
    <h3>{{item.username}}</h3>
    <img ng-src="{{item.fileLocation}}"/>
 </li>
```

Also in your controller you probably don't need to parse the data:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8087/sportsrest/binaries/' }).success(function (data) {
     $scope.cart = data; // response data 
})
```

Comment: thanks for replay.it is not working. Do i need to change anything in controller

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer to illustrate what you might try changing in the `success` callback of your AJAX request.

Comment: @darvin It is showing empty html page.  Do i need to assign $scope.item=data; in my controller?

Comment: Have you checked for potential errors in the Console?

Comment: Inside the `success` callback if you add `console.log(data);` can you see the correct JSON printed in the console?

Comment: i changed in controller as you said. it is showing empty page with no errors

Answer (score 1):

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive has not been used properly.

This should work for you ..

In the HTML code:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in cart._embedded.binaries">
             <h3>{{item.username}}</h3>
             <img ng-src="{{item.fileLocation}}"/>
 </li>
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/85kykut0/3/)

Comment: @Ashokkumar updated the code with a DEMO. If it's still not working for you, then I would suggest checking your JSON, if its, as you have mentioned in your question

Comment: Your demo code differs from the code you used in the answer, this might confuse.

Comment: @ijade thanks for replay,  i will try it and inform you

Comment: @ijade thanks for replay.  once i will try and get back to you

Comment: @ijade thanks for your support and replay.. your DEMO helped me.  Thank you once again. Keep rocking